# Inverting a 4x4 matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am looking for a sample code implementation on how to invert a 4x4 matrix. I know there is Gaussian eleminiation, LU decomposition, etc., but instead of looking at them in detail I am really just looking for the code to do this.

Language ideally C++, data is available in array of 16 floats in column-major order.

Comment: Is this homework?  If not (e.g. you're just trying to solve Ax=b), then trying to explicitly compute an inverse may not be what you want to do.

Comment: it is not homework. it is for a personal project. and i dont want to "waste" time on learning matrix inversion for 4x4 which seems quite complicated compared to 3x3

Comment: I do not think this is a stupid question that deserves -1 score.

Comment: if your matrix is a rotation/scaling/translation one, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155670/invert-4x4-matrix-numerical-most-stable-solution-needed?rq=1 & https://web.archive.org/web/20130806093214/http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs248-98-fall/Final/q4.html

Comment: you may also be interested in this if you want a bit more performance https://lxjk.github.io/2017/09/03/Fast-4x4-Matrix-Inverse-with-SSE-SIMD-Explained.html and you cannot process multiple matrices at a time

Comment: This problem has been solved in every language.  This question tells me that you lack in Google search skills.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-perform-lu-decomposition-of-any-matrix

Answer (score 121, accepted):

here:

```
bool gluInvertMatrix(const double m[16], double invOut[16])
{
    double inv[16], det;
    int i;

    inv[0] = m[5]  * m[10] * m[15] - 
             m[5]  * m[11] * m[14] - 
             m[9]  * m[6]  * m[15] + 
             m[9]  * m[7]  * m[14] +
             m[13] * m[6]  * m[11] - 
             m[13] * m[7]  * m[10];

    inv[4] = -m[4]  * m[10] * m[15] + 
              m[4]  * m[11] * m[14] + 
              m[8]  * m[6]  * m[15] - 
              m[8]  * m[7]  * m[14] - 
              m[12] * m[6]  * m[11] + 
              m[12] * m[7]  * m[10];

    inv[8] = m[4]  * m[9] * m[15] - 
             m[4]  * m[11] * m[13] - 
             m[8]  * m[5] * m[15] + 
             m[8]  * m[7] * m[13] + 
             m[12] * m[5] * m[11] - 
             m[12] * m[7] * m[9];

    inv[12] = -m[4]  * m[9] * m[14] + 
               m[4]  * m[10] * m[13] +
               m[8]  * m[5] * m[14] - 
               m[8]  * m[6] * m[13] - 
               m[12] * m[5] * m[10] + 
               m[12] * m[6] * m[9];

    inv[1] = -m[1]  * m[10] * m[15] + 
              m[1]  * m[11] * m[14] + 
              m[9]  * m[2] * m[15] - 
              m[9]  * m[3] * m[14] - 
              m[13] * m[2] * m[11] + 
              m[13] * m[3] * m[10];

    inv[5] = m[0]  * m[10] * m[15] - 
             m[0]  * m[11] * m[14] - 
             m[8]  * m[2] * m[15] + 
             m[8]  * m[3] * m[14] + 
             m[12] * m[2] * m[11] - 
             m[12] * m[3] * m[10];

    inv[9] = -m[0]  * m[9] * m[15] + 
              m[0]  * m[11] * m[13] + 
              m[8]  * m[1] * m[15] - 
              m[8]  * m[3] * m[13] - 
              m[12] * m[1] * m[11] + 
              m[12] * m[3] * m[9];

    inv[13] = m[0]  * m[9] * m[14] - 
              m[0]  * m[10] * m[13] - 
              m[8]  * m[1] * m[14] + 
              m[8]  * m[2] * m[13] + 
              m[12] * m[1] * m[10] - 
              m[12] * m[2] * m[9];

    inv[2] = m[1]  * m[6] * m[15] - 
             m[1]  * m[7] * m[14] - 
             m[5]  * m[2] * m[15] + 
             m[5]  * m[3] * m[14] + 
             m[13] * m[2] * m[7] - 
             m[13] * m[3] * m[6];

    inv[6] = -m[0]  * m[6] * m[15] + 
              m[0]  * m[7] * m[14] + 
              m[4]  * m[2] * m[15] - 
              m[4]  * m[3] * m[14] - 
              m[12] * m[2] * m[7] + 
              m[12] * m[3] * m[6];

    inv[10] = m[0]  * m[5] * m[15] - 
              m[0]  * m[7] * m[13] - 
              m[4]  * m[1] * m[15] + 
              m[4]  * m[3] * m[13] + 
              m[12] * m[1] * m[7] - 
              m[12] * m[3] * m[5];

    inv[14] = -m[0]  * m[5] * m[14] + 
               m[0]  * m[6] * m[13] + 
               m[4]  * m[1] * m[14] - 
               m[4]  * m[2] * m[13] - 
               m[12] * m[1] * m[6] + 
               m[12] * m[2] * m[5];

    inv[3] = -m[1] * m[6] * m[11] + 
              m[1] * m[7] * m[10] + 
              m[5] * m[2] * m[11] - 
              m[5] * m[3] * m[10] - 
              m[9] * m[2] * m[7] + 
              m[9] * m[3] * m[6];

    inv[7] = m[0] * m[6] * m[11] - 
             m[0] * m[7] * m[10] - 
             m[4] * m[2] * m[11] + 
             m[4] * m[3] * m[10] + 
             m[8] * m[2] * m[7] - 
             m[8] * m[3] * m[6];

    inv[11] = -m[0] * m[5] * m[11] + 
               m[0] * m[7] * m[9] + 
               m[4] * m[1] * m[11] - 
               m[4] * m[3] * m[9] - 
               m[8] * m[1] * m[7] + 
               m[8] * m[3] * m[5];

    inv[15] = m[0] * m[5] * m[10] - 
              m[0] * m[6] * m[9] - 
              m[4] * m[1] * m[10] + 
              m[4] * m[2] * m[9] + 
              m[8] * m[1] * m[6] - 
              m[8] * m[2] * m[5];

    det = m[0] * inv[0] + m[1] * inv[4] + m[2] * inv[8] + m[3] * inv[12];

    if (det == 0)
        return false;

    det = 1.0 / det;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        invOut[i] = inv[i] * det;

    return true;
}
```

This was lifted from [MESA](http://www.mesa3d.org/) implementation of the GLU library.

Comment: You probably wouldn't want it any other way.

Comment: Yes I would.  Compilers are perfectly capable of unrolling loops, especially when you tell them to.

Comment: Even if they wouldn't that might be time to invest into metaprogramming (here's place for loop). I workarounded one compiler which did not unroll trivial loops by using m4.

Comment: Sadly, that code isn't really that straightforward to make in a loopable way to begin with, much less a way that a compiler can adequately unroll.  Also, that code comes from a rather old C library which has a LOT of very fiddly optimizations, and it's code that works already (and has been thoroughly tested and proven by thousands of Linux OpenGL programs at this point) so why rewrite it?

Comment: Is this for column major or row major ordered matrices?

Comment: Imagist: It wasn't derived from an unrolled loop. That really is the simplest way of writing it.

Comment: Zoomulator: Awesomely it is for both! This is because inverse(transpose(A)) = transpose(inverse(A)).

Comment: Why not calculate the determinant *first*? Is this attempting realtime consistency or something?

Comment: @Imagist you can check my answer if you're looking for a 'looping variant'. Aggressive compiler optimisations won't fix the performance hit...

Comment: @dfeuer It would take 72 multiplications to get the determinant first.  While doing it first would actually be faster in case of non-invertible matrix, for an invertible matrix it saves 68 multiplications by doing it after.  Also there's the bonus of having less code this way.

Comment: Comatrix-based inversion like this is going to be very prone to roundoff error (look at all the potential for catastrophic cancellation). Stabler versions include branches (ie. pivoting) however, so this is kind of a trade-off. I suspect that Mesa programmers prefer performance here.

Comment: Strainghtforward implementation.
@crazyjoe: You could move the calculation of inv[0], inv[4], inv[8], inv[12] to the top and calculate the determinant earlier, so you optimize the non-invertible path too...

Comment: I don't understand, this code is moving m12,m13,m14 to m3,m7,m11 where other algorithms will just leave the last column in place.

Comment: @BrynnMahsman From the looks of it, it's based on Minors, cofactors and adjugate - https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-minors-cofactors-adjugate.html. The other method would be column and row operations but I think this would be difficult to code as you'd have to use conditional logic

Comment: @fluffy This is just using determinants isn't it? This should be fairly "loopable".

Comment: @whn Where are the access patterns that can be turned into unrollable loops in a way that the compiler would be likely to be able to unroll this concisely? Also why ping me specifically on a comment I posted on an answer 9 years ago?

Comment: I should add, this code works very well in general, but it will produce quite incorrect results when the determinant of the matrix is low (say, <= 1e-4).

Answer (score 34):

If anyone looking for more costumized code and "easier to read", then I got this

```
var A2323 = m.m22 * m.m33 - m.m23 * m.m32 ;
var A1323 = m.m21 * m.m33 - m.m23 * m.m31 ;
var A1223 = m.m21 * m.m32 - m.m22 * m.m31 ;
var A0323 = m.m20 * m.m33 - m.m23 * m.m30 ;
var A0223 = m.m20 * m.m32 - m.m22 * m.m30 ;
var A0123 = m.m20 * m.m31 - m.m21 * m.m30 ;
var A2313 = m.m12 * m.m33 - m.m13 * m.m32 ;
var A1313 = m.m11 * m.m33 - m.m13 * m.m31 ;
var A1213 = m.m11 * m.m32 - m.m12 * m.m31 ;
var A2312 = m.m12 * m.m23 - m.m13 * m.m22 ;
var A1312 = m.m11 * m.m23 - m.m13 * m.m21 ;
var A1212 = m.m11 * m.m22 - m.m12 * m.m21 ;
var A0313 = m.m10 * m.m33 - m.m13 * m.m30 ;
var A0213 = m.m10 * m.m32 - m.m12 * m.m30 ;
var A0312 = m.m10 * m.m23 - m.m13 * m.m20 ;
var A0212 = m.m10 * m.m22 - m.m12 * m.m20 ;
var A0113 = m.m10 * m.m31 - m.m11 * m.m30 ;
var A0112 = m.m10 * m.m21 - m.m11 * m.m20 ;

var det = m.m00 * ( m.m11 * A2323 - m.m12 * A1323 + m.m13 * A1223 ) 
    - m.m01 * ( m.m10 * A2323 - m.m12 * A0323 + m.m13 * A0223 ) 
    + m.m02 * ( m.m10 * A1323 - m.m11 * A0323 + m.m13 * A0123 ) 
    - m.m03 * ( m.m10 * A1223 - m.m11 * A0223 + m.m12 * A0123 ) ;
det = 1 / det;

return new Matrix4x4() {
   m00 = det *   ( m.m11 * A2323 - m.m12 * A1323 + m.m13 * A1223 ),
   m01 = det * - ( m.m01 * A2323 - m.m02 * A1323 + m.m03 * A1223 ),
   m02 = det *   ( m.m01 * A2313 - m.m02 * A1313 + m.m03 * A1213 ),
   m03 = det * - ( m.m01 * A2312 - m.m02 * A1312 + m.m03 * A1212 ),
   m10 = det * - ( m.m10 * A2323 - m.m12 * A0323 + m.m13 * A0223 ),
   m11 = det *   ( m.m00 * A2323 - m.m02 * A0323 + m.m03 * A0223 ),
   m12 = det * - ( m.m00 * A2313 - m.m02 * A0313 + m.m03 * A0213 ),
   m13 = det *   ( m.m00 * A2312 - m.m02 * A0312 + m.m03 * A0212 ),
   m20 = det *   ( m.m10 * A1323 - m.m11 * A0323 + m.m13 * A0123 ),
   m21 = det * - ( m.m00 * A1323 - m.m01 * A0323 + m.m03 * A0123 ),
   m22 = det *   ( m.m00 * A1313 - m.m01 * A0313 + m.m03 * A0113 ),
   m23 = det * - ( m.m00 * A1312 - m.m01 * A0312 + m.m03 * A0112 ),
   m30 = det * - ( m.m10 * A1223 - m.m11 * A0223 + m.m12 * A0123 ),
   m31 = det *   ( m.m00 * A1223 - m.m01 * A0223 + m.m02 * A0123 ),
   m32 = det * - ( m.m00 * A1213 - m.m01 * A0213 + m.m02 * A0113 ),
   m33 = det *   ( m.m00 * A1212 - m.m01 * A0212 + m.m02 * A0112 ),
};
```

I don't write the code, but my program did. I made a small program *to make a program* that calculate the determinant and inverse of any N-matrix.

I do it because once in the past I need a code that inverses 5x5 matrix, but nobody in the earth have done this so I made one.

Take a look about the program [here](https://github.com/WelloSoft/N-Matrix-Programmer).

EDIT: The matrix layout is row-by-row (meaning `m01` is in the first row and second column). Also the language is C#, but should be easy to convert into C.

Comment: 116 float multiplications compared with 200 for the accepted answer. (and determinant checking *before* doing majority of calculation)

Comment: This answer feels like a gift from God. You even use the same naming convention for matrix elements as I do.

Comment: Really good answer, but regarding this " I need a code that inverses 5x5 matrix, but nobody in the earth have done this" --- The reason for that is probably, that it is cheaper to use a direct solver (Gauss, LU) than using a formula based on determinants (Cramers rule?).

Answer (score 7):

I 'rolled up' the MESA implementation (also wrote a couple of unit tests to ensure it actually works).

Here:

```
float invf(int i,int j,const float* m){

    int o = 2+(j-i);

    i += 4+o;
    j += 4-o;

    #define e(a,b) m[ ((j+b)%4)*4 + ((i+a)%4) ]

    float inv =
     + e(+1,-1)*e(+0,+0)*e(-1,+1)
     + e(+1,+1)*e(+0,-1)*e(-1,+0)
     + e(-1,-1)*e(+1,+0)*e(+0,+1)
     - e(-1,-1)*e(+0,+0)*e(+1,+1)
     - e(-1,+1)*e(+0,-1)*e(+1,+0)
     - e(+1,-1)*e(-1,+0)*e(+0,+1);

    return (o%2)?inv : -inv;

    #undef e

}

bool inverseMatrix4x4(const float *m, float *out)
{

    float inv[16];

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            inv[j*4+i] = invf(i,j,m);

    double D = 0;

    for(int k=0;k<4;k++) D += m[k] * inv[k*4];

    if (D == 0) return false;

    D = 1.0 / D;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        out[i] = inv[i] * D;

    return true;

}
```

I wrote a little about this and display the pattern of positive/negative factors [on my blog](http://gamesxmath.tumblr.com/post/86495837013/inverting-a-4x4-matrix-using-c-code-float).

As suggested by @LiraNuna, on many platforms hardware accelerated versions of such routines are available so I'm happy to have a 'backup version' that's readable and concise.

**Note**: this may run 3.5 times slower or worse than the MESA implementation. You can shift the pattern of factors to remove some additions etc... but it would lose in readability and still won't be very fast.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a C++ matrix library with a lot of functions, have a look at Eigen library - http://eigen.tuxfamily.org

Answer (score 6):

This is the C++ version for [@willnode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446912/5373986)

```
template<typename Matrix>
static inline void InvertMatrix4(const Matrix& m, Matrix& im, double& det)
{
    double A2323 = m(2, 2) * m(3, 3) - m(2, 3) * m(3, 2);
    double A1323 = m(2, 1) * m(3, 3) - m(2, 3) * m(3, 1);
    double A1223 = m(2, 1) * m(3, 2) - m(2, 2) * m(3, 1);
    double A0323 = m(2, 0) * m(3, 3) - m(2, 3) * m(3, 0);
    double A0223 = m(2, 0) * m(3, 2) - m(2, 2) * m(3, 0);
    double A0123 = m(2, 0) * m(3, 1) - m(2, 1) * m(3, 0);
    double A2313 = m(1, 2) * m(3, 3) - m(1, 3) * m(3, 2);
    double A1313 = m(1, 1) * m(3, 3) - m(1, 3) * m(3, 1);
    double A1213 = m(1, 1) * m(3, 2) - m(1, 2) * m(3, 1);
    double A2312 = m(1, 2) * m(2, 3) - m(1, 3) * m(2, 2);
    double A1312 = m(1, 1) * m(2, 3) - m(1, 3) * m(2, 1);
    double A1212 = m(1, 1) * m(2, 2) - m(1, 2) * m(2, 1);
    double A0313 = m(1, 0) * m(3, 3) - m(1, 3) * m(3, 0);
    double A0213 = m(1, 0) * m(3, 2) - m(1, 2) * m(3, 0);
    double A0312 = m(1, 0) * m(2, 3) - m(1, 3) * m(2, 0);
    double A0212 = m(1, 0) * m(2, 2) - m(1, 2) * m(2, 0);
    double A0113 = m(1, 0) * m(3, 1) - m(1, 1) * m(3, 0);
    double A0112 = m(1, 0) * m(2, 1) - m(1, 1) * m(2, 0);

    det = m(0, 0) * ( m(1, 1) * A2323 - m(1, 2) * A1323 + m(1, 3) * A1223 )
        - m(0, 1) * ( m(1, 0) * A2323 - m(1, 2) * A0323 + m(1, 3) * A0223 )
        + m(0, 2) * ( m(1, 0) * A1323 - m(1, 1) * A0323 + m(1, 3) * A0123 )
        - m(0, 3) * ( m(1, 0) * A1223 - m(1, 1) * A0223 + m(1, 2) * A0123 );
    det = 1 / det;

    im(0, 0) = det *   ( m(1, 1) * A2323 - m(1, 2) * A1323 + m(1, 3) * A1223 );
    im(0, 1) = det * - ( m(0, 1) * A2323 - m(0, 2) * A1323 + m(0, 3) * A1223 );
    im(0, 2) = det *   ( m(0, 1) * A2313 - m(0, 2) * A1313 + m(0, 3) * A1213 );
    im(0, 3) = det * - ( m(0, 1) * A2312 - m(0, 2) * A1312 + m(0, 3) * A1212 );
    im(1, 0) = det * - ( m(1, 0) * A2323 - m(1, 2) * A0323 + m(1, 3) * A0223 );
    im(1, 1) = det *   ( m(0, 0) * A2323 - m(0, 2) * A0323 + m(0, 3) * A0223 );
    im(1, 2) = det * - ( m(0, 0) * A2313 - m(0, 2) * A0313 + m(0, 3) * A0213 );
    im(1, 3) = det *   ( m(0, 0) * A2312 - m(0, 2) * A0312 + m(0, 3) * A0212 );
    im(2, 0) = det *   ( m(1, 0) * A1323 - m(1, 1) * A0323 + m(1, 3) * A0123 );
    im(2, 1) = det * - ( m(0, 0) * A1323 - m(0, 1) * A0323 + m(0, 3) * A0123 );
    im(2, 2) = det *   ( m(0, 0) * A1313 - m(0, 1) * A0313 + m(0, 3) * A0113 );
    im(2, 3) = det * - ( m(0, 0) * A1312 - m(0, 1) * A0312 + m(0, 3) * A0112 );
    im(3, 0) = det * - ( m(1, 0) * A1223 - m(1, 1) * A0223 + m(1, 2) * A0123 );
    im(3, 1) = det *   ( m(0, 0) * A1223 - m(0, 1) * A0223 + m(0, 2) * A0123 );
    im(3, 2) = det * - ( m(0, 0) * A1213 - m(0, 1) * A0213 + m(0, 2) * A0113 );
    im(3, 3) = det *   ( m(0, 0) * A1212 - m(0, 1) * A0212 + m(0, 2) * A0112 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) or look the code up in it.

Edit: You seem to want the [Linear Algebra](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linear-Algebra.html) section.

Comment: i did infact look at the matrix struct from gsl, but it doesnt seem to have a function for determinant or inversion.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @shoosh to check out MESA implementations, I found that matrix inversion looks quite different in more recent mesa releases. I suppose those are good improvements. Here's the matrix inversion code from [Mesa-17.3.9](https://mesa.freedesktop.org/archive/mesa-17.3.9.tar.xz):

```
/* Returns true for success, false for failure (singular matrix) */
bool DirectVolumeRenderer::_mesa_invert_matrix_general( GLfloat out[16], const GLfloat in[16] )
{
    /**
     * References an element of 4x4 matrix.
     * Calculate the linear storage index of the element and references it. 
     */
    #define MAT(m,r,c) (m)[(c)*4+(r)]
    /**
     * Swaps the values of two floating point variables.
     */
    #define SWAP_ROWS(a, b) { GLfloat *_tmp = a; (a)=(b); (b)=_tmp; }

    const GLfloat *m = in;
    GLfloat wtmp[4][8];
    GLfloat m0, m1, m2, m3, s;
    GLfloat *r0, *r1, *r2, *r3;

    r0 = wtmp[0], r1 = wtmp[1], r2 = wtmp[2], r3 = wtmp[3];

    r0[0] = MAT(m,0,0), r0[1] = MAT(m,0,1),
    r0[2] = MAT(m,0,2), r0[3] = MAT(m,0,3),
    r0[4] = 1.0, r0[5] = r0[6] = r0[7] = 0.0,

    r1[0] = MAT(m,1,0), r1[1] = MAT(m,1,1),
    r1[2] = MAT(m,1,2), r1[3] = MAT(m,1,3),
    r1[5] = 1.0, r1[4] = r1[6] = r1[7] = 0.0,

    r2[0] = MAT(m,2,0), r2[1] = MAT(m,2,1),
    r2[2] = MAT(m,2,2), r2[3] = MAT(m,2,3),
    r2[6] = 1.0, r2[4] = r2[5] = r2[7] = 0.0,

    r3[0] = MAT(m,3,0), r3[1] = MAT(m,3,1),
    r3[2] = MAT(m,3,2), r3[3] = MAT(m,3,3),
    r3[7] = 1.0, r3[4] = r3[5] = r3[6] = 0.0;

    /* choose pivot - or die */
    if (fabsf(r3[0])>fabsf(r2[0])) SWAP_ROWS(r3, r2);
    if (fabsf(r2[0])>fabsf(r1[0])) SWAP_ROWS(r2, r1);
    if (fabsf(r1[0])>fabsf(r0[0])) SWAP_ROWS(r1, r0);
    if (0.0F == r0[0])
        return false;

    /* eliminate first variable     */
    m1 = r1[0]/r0[0]; m2 = r2[0]/r0[0]; m3 = r3[0]/r0[0];
    s = r0[1]; r1[1] -= m1 * s; r2[1] -= m2 * s; r3[1] -= m3 * s;
    s = r0[2]; r1[2] -= m1 * s; r2[2] -= m2 * s; r3[2] -= m3 * s;
    s = r0[3]; r1[3] -= m1 * s; r2[3] -= m2 * s; r3[3] -= m3 * s;
    s = r0[4];
    if (s != 0.0F) { r1[4] -= m1 * s; r2[4] -= m2 * s; r3[4] -= m3 * s; }
    s = r0[5];
    if (s != 0.0F) { r1[5] -= m1 * s; r2[5] -= m2 * s; r3[5] -= m3 * s; }
    s = r0[6];
    if (s != 0.0F) { r1[6] -= m1 * s; r2[6] -= m2 * s; r3[6] -= m3 * s; }
    s = r0[7];
    if (s != 0.0F) { r1[7] -= m1 * s; r2[7] -= m2 * s; r3[7] -= m3 * s; }

    /* choose pivot - or die */
    if (fabsf(r3[1])>fabsf(r2[1])) SWAP_ROWS(r3, r2);
    if (fabsf(r2[1])>fabsf(r1[1])) SWAP_ROWS(r2, r1);
    if (0.0F == r1[1])
        return false;

    /* eliminate second variable */
    m2 = r2[1]/r1[1]; m3 = r3[1]/r1[1];
    r2[2] -= m2 * r1[2]; r3[2] -= m3 * r1[2];
    r2[3] -= m2 * r1[3]; r3[3] -= m3 * r1[3];
    s = r1[4]; if (0.0F != s) { r2[4] -= m2 * s; r3[4] -= m3 * s; }
    s = r1[5]; if (0.0F != s) { r2[5] -= m2 * s; r3[5] -= m3 * s; }
    s = r1[6]; if (0.0F != s) { r2[6] -= m2 * s; r3[6] -= m3 * s; }
    s = r1[7]; if (0.0F != s) { r2[7] -= m2 * s; r3[7] -= m3 * s; }

    /* choose pivot - or die */
    if (fabsf(r3[2])>fabsf(r2[2])) SWAP_ROWS(r3, r2);
    if (0.0F == r2[2])
        return false;

    /* eliminate third variable */
    m3 = r3[2]/r2[2];
    r3[3] -= m3 * r2[3], r3[4] -= m3 * r2[4],
    r3[5] -= m3 * r2[5], r3[6] -= m3 * r2[6],
    r3[7] -= m3 * r2[7];

    /* last check */
    if (0.0F == r3[3])
        return false;

    s = 1.0F/r3[3];             /* now back substitute row 3 */
    r3[4] *= s; r3[5] *= s; r3[6] *= s; r3[7] *= s;

    m2 = r2[3];                 /* now back substitute row 2 */
    s  = 1.0F/r2[2];
    r2[4] = s * (r2[4] - r3[4] * m2), r2[5] = s * (r2[5] - r3[5] * m2),
    r2[6] = s * (r2[6] - r3[6] * m2), r2[7] = s * (r2[7] - r3[7] * m2);
    m1 = r1[3];
    r1[4] -= r3[4] * m1, r1[5] -= r3[5] * m1,
    r1[6] -= r3[6] * m1, r1[7] -= r3[7] * m1;
    m0 = r0[3];
    r0[4] -= r3[4] * m0, r0[5] -= r3[5] * m0,
    r0[6] -= r3[6] * m0, r0[7] -= r3[7] * m0;

    m1 = r1[2];                 /* now back substitute row 1 */
    s  = 1.0F/r1[1];
    r1[4] = s * (r1[4] - r2[4] * m1), r1[5] = s * (r1[5] - r2[5] * m1),
    r1[6] = s * (r1[6] - r2[6] * m1), r1[7] = s * (r1[7] - r2[7] * m1);
    m0 = r0[2];
    r0[4] -= r2[4] * m0, r0[5] -= r2[5] * m0,
    r0[6] -= r2[6] * m0, r0[7] -= r2[7] * m0;

    m0 = r0[1];                 /* now back substitute row 0 */
    s  = 1.0F/r0[0];
    r0[4] = s * (r0[4] - r1[4] * m0), r0[5] = s * (r0[5] - r1[5] * m0),
    r0[6] = s * (r0[6] - r1[6] * m0), r0[7] = s * (r0[7] - r1[7] * m0);

    MAT(out,0,0) = r0[4]; MAT(out,0,1) = r0[5],
    MAT(out,0,2) = r0[6]; MAT(out,0,3) = r0[7],
    MAT(out,1,0) = r1[4]; MAT(out,1,1) = r1[5],
    MAT(out,1,2) = r1[6]; MAT(out,1,3) = r1[7],
    MAT(out,2,0) = r2[4]; MAT(out,2,1) = r2[5],
    MAT(out,2,2) = r2[6]; MAT(out,2,3) = r2[7],
    MAT(out,3,0) = r3[4]; MAT(out,3,1) = r3[5],
    MAT(out,3,2) = r3[6]; MAT(out,3,3) = r3[7];

    #undef SWAP_ROWS
    #undef MAT

    return true;
}
```

Note: you can find this piece of code in the mesa code base: `mesa-17.3.9/src/mesa/math/m_matrix.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small (just one header) C++ [vector math](http://www.trenki.net/content/view/16/36/) library (geared towards 3D programming). If you use it, keep in mind that layout of its matrices in memory is inverted comparing to what OpenGL expects, I had fun time figuring it out...

Answer (score 1):

You can make it faster according to this [blog](http://www.freevec.org/function/inverse_matrix_4x4_using_partitioning).

```
#define SUBP(i,j) input[i][j]
#define SUBQ(i,j) input[i][2+j]
#define SUBR(i,j) input[2+i][j]
#define SUBS(i,j) input[2+i][2+j]

#define OUTP(i,j) output[i][j]
#define OUTQ(i,j) output[i][2+j]
#define OUTR(i,j) output[2+i][j]
#define OUTS(i,j) output[2+i][2+j]

#define INVP(i,j) invP[i][j]
#define INVPQ(i,j) invPQ[i][j]
#define RINVP(i,j) RinvP[i][j]
#define INVPQ(i,j) invPQ[i][j]
#define RINVPQ(i,j) RinvPQ[i][j]
#define INVPQR(i,j) invPQR[i][j]
#define INVS(i,j) invS[i][j]

#define MULTI(MAT1, MAT2, MAT3) \
    MAT3(0,0)=MAT1(0,0)*MAT2(0,0) + MAT1(0,1)*MAT2(1,0); \
MAT3(0,1)=MAT1(0,0)*MAT2(0,1) + MAT1(0,1)*MAT2(1,1); \
MAT3(1,0)=MAT1(1,0)*MAT2(0,0) + MAT1(1,1)*MAT2(1,0); \
MAT3(1,1)=MAT1(1,0)*MAT2(0,1) + MAT1(1,1)*MAT2(1,1);

#define INV(MAT1, MAT2) \
    _det = 1.0 / (MAT1(0,0) * MAT1(1,1) - MAT1(0,1) * MAT1(1,0)); \
MAT2(0,0) = MAT1(1,1) * _det; \
MAT2(1,1) = MAT1(0,0) * _det; \
MAT2(0,1) = -MAT1(0,1) * _det; \
MAT2(1,0) = -MAT1(1,0) * _det; \

#define SUBTRACT(MAT1, MAT2, MAT3) \
    MAT3(0,0)=MAT1(0,0) - MAT2(0,0); \
MAT3(0,1)=MAT1(0,1) - MAT2(0,1); \
MAT3(1,0)=MAT1(1,0) - MAT2(1,0); \
MAT3(1,1)=MAT1(1,1) - MAT2(1,1);

#define NEGATIVE(MAT) \
    MAT(0,0)=-MAT(0,0); \
MAT(0,1)=-MAT(0,1); \
MAT(1,0)=-MAT(1,0); \
MAT(1,1)=-MAT(1,1);


void getInvertMatrix(complex<double> input[4][4], complex<double> output[4][4]) {
    complex<double> _det;
    complex<double> invP[2][2];
    complex<double> invPQ[2][2];
    complex<double> RinvP[2][2];
    complex<double> RinvPQ[2][2];
    complex<double> invPQR[2][2];
    complex<double> invS[2][2];


    INV(SUBP, INVP);
    MULTI(SUBR, INVP, RINVP);
    MULTI(INVP, SUBQ, INVPQ);
    MULTI(RINVP, SUBQ, RINVPQ);
    SUBTRACT(SUBS, RINVPQ, INVS);
    INV(INVS, OUTS);
    NEGATIVE(OUTS);
    MULTI(OUTS, RINVP, OUTR);
    MULTI(INVPQ, OUTS, OUTQ);
    MULTI(INVPQ, OUTR, INVPQR);
    SUBTRACT(INVP, INVPQR, OUTP);
}
```

This is not a complete implementation because **P** may not be invertible, but you can combine this code with MESA implementation to get a better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a 2d case which might be useful for someone else:

```
inline bool invert4by4matrix(mat m, mat inv_m)
 {

        inv_m->v[0][0] = m->v[1][1] * m->v[2][2] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[1][1] * m->v[2][3] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[2][1] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[2][1] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[3][1] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[2][3] -
                         m->v[3][1] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[2][2];

        inv_m->v[1][0] = -m->v[1][0] * m->v[2][2] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[2][3] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[2][3] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[2][2];

        inv_m->v[2][0] = m->v[1][0] * m->v[2][1] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[2][3] * m->v[3][1] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[3][1] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[2][3] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[2][1];

        inv_m->v[3][0] = -m->v[1][0] * m->v[2][1] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[2][2] * m->v[3][1] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[3][1] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[2][2] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[2][1];

        inv_m->v[0][1] = -m->v[0][1] * m->v[2][2] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[0][1] * m->v[2][3] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[2][1] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[2][1] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[3][1] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[2][3] +
                         m->v[3][1] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[2][2];

        inv_m->v[1][1] = m->v[0][0] * m->v[2][2] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[2][3] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[2][3] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[2][2];

        inv_m->v[2][1] = -m->v[0][0] * m->v[2][1] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[2][3] * m->v[3][1] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[3][1] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[2][3] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[2][1];

        inv_m->v[3][1] = m->v[0][0] * m->v[2][1] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[2][2] * m->v[3][1] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[3][1] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[2][2] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[2][1];

        inv_m->v[0][2] = m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[1][1] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[1][1] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[3][1] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[1][3] -
                         m->v[3][1] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[1][2];

        inv_m->v[1][2] = -m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[1][3] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[1][2];

        inv_m->v[2][2] = m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[3][3] -
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[3][1] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[3][3] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[3][1] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][3] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[1][1];

        inv_m->v[3][2] = -m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[3][2] +
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[3][1] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[3][2] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[3][1] -
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][2] +
                         m->v[3][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[1][1];

        inv_m->v[0][3] = -m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[2][3] +
                         m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[2][2] +
                         m->v[1][1] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[2][3] -
                         m->v[1][1] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[2][2] -
                         m->v[2][1] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[1][3] +
                         m->v[2][1] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[1][2];

        inv_m->v[1][3] = m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[2][3] -
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[2][2] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[2][3] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[2][2] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[1][3] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[1][2];

        inv_m->v[2][3] = -m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[2][3] +
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][3] * m->v[2][1] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[2][3] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[2][1] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][3] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][3] * m->v[1][1];

        inv_m->v[3][3] = m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][1] * m->v[2][2] -
                         m->v[0][0] * m->v[1][2] * m->v[2][1] -
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[2][2] +
                         m->v[1][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[2][1] +
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][1] * m->v[1][2] -
                         m->v[2][0] * m->v[0][2] * m->v[1][1];

        double det = m->v[0][0] * inv_m->v[0][0] +
                     m->v[0][1] * inv_m->v[1][0] +
                     m->v[0][2] * inv_m->v[2][0] +
                     m->v[0][3] * inv_m->v[3][0];

        if (det == 0)
            return false;

        det = 1.0 / det;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                inv_m->v[i][j] = inv_m->v[i][j] * det;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the inverse matrix of 4x4 matrix, then I recommend to use a library like [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) :

Anyway, you can do it from scratch.  The following implementation is similar to the implementation of [`glm::inverse`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00371.html#gaed509fe8129b01e4f20a6d0de5690091), but it is not as highly optimized:

```cpp
bool InverseMat44( const GLfloat m[16], GLfloat invOut[16] )
{
    float inv[16], det;
    int i;

    inv[0]  =  m[5] * m[10] * m[15] - m[5] * m[11] * m[14] - m[9] * m[6] * m[15] + m[9] * m[7] * m[14] + m[13] * m[6] * m[11] - m[13] * m[7] * m[10];
    inv[4]  = -m[4] * m[10] * m[15] + m[4] * m[11] * m[14] + m[8] * m[6] * m[15] - m[8] * m[7] * m[14] - m[12] * m[6] * m[11] + m[12] * m[7] * m[10];
    inv[8]  =  m[4] * m[9]  * m[15] - m[4] * m[11] * m[13] - m[8] * m[5] * m[15] + m[8] * m[7] * m[13] + m[12] * m[5] * m[11] - m[12] * m[7] * m[9];
    inv[12] = -m[4] * m[9]  * m[14] + m[4] * m[10] * m[13] + m[8] * m[5] * m[14] - m[8] * m[6] * m[13] - m[12] * m[5] * m[10] + m[12] * m[6] * m[9];
    inv[1]  = -m[1] * m[10] * m[15] + m[1] * m[11] * m[14] + m[9] * m[2] * m[15] - m[9] * m[3] * m[14] - m[13] * m[2] * m[11] + m[13] * m[3] * m[10];
    inv[5]  =  m[0] * m[10] * m[15] - m[0] * m[11] * m[14] - m[8] * m[2] * m[15] + m[8] * m[3] * m[14] + m[12] * m[2] * m[11] - m[12] * m[3] * m[10];
    inv[9]  = -m[0] * m[9]  * m[15] + m[0] * m[11] * m[13] + m[8] * m[1] * m[15] - m[8] * m[3] * m[13] - m[12] * m[1] * m[11] + m[12] * m[3] * m[9];
    inv[13] =  m[0] * m[9]  * m[14] - m[0] * m[10] * m[13] - m[8] * m[1] * m[14] + m[8] * m[2] * m[13] + m[12] * m[1] * m[10] - m[12] * m[2] * m[9];
    inv[2]  =  m[1] * m[6]  * m[15] - m[1] * m[7]  * m[14] - m[5] * m[2] * m[15] + m[5] * m[3] * m[14] + m[13] * m[2] * m[7]  - m[13] * m[3] * m[6];
    inv[6]  = -m[0] * m[6]  * m[15] + m[0] * m[7]  * m[14] + m[4] * m[2] * m[15] - m[4] * m[3] * m[14] - m[12] * m[2] * m[7]  + m[12] * m[3] * m[6];
    inv[10] =  m[0] * m[5]  * m[15] - m[0] * m[7]  * m[13] - m[4] * m[1] * m[15] + m[4] * m[3] * m[13] + m[12] * m[1] * m[7]  - m[12] * m[3] * m[5];
    inv[14] = -m[0] * m[5]  * m[14] + m[0] * m[6]  * m[13] + m[4] * m[1] * m[14] - m[4] * m[2] * m[13] - m[12] * m[1] * m[6]  + m[12] * m[2] * m[5];
    inv[3]  = -m[1] * m[6]  * m[11] + m[1] * m[7]  * m[10] + m[5] * m[2] * m[11] - m[5] * m[3] * m[10] - m[9]  * m[2] * m[7]  + m[9]  * m[3] * m[6];
    inv[7]  =  m[0] * m[6]  * m[11] - m[0] * m[7]  * m[10] - m[4] * m[2] * m[11] + m[4] * m[3] * m[10] + m[8]  * m[2] * m[7]  - m[8]  * m[3] * m[6];
    inv[11] = -m[0] * m[5]  * m[11] + m[0] * m[7]  * m[9]  + m[4] * m[1] * m[11] - m[4] * m[3] * m[9]  - m[8]  * m[1] * m[7]  + m[8]  * m[3] * m[5];
    inv[15] =  m[0] * m[5]  * m[10] - m[0] * m[6]  * m[9]  - m[4] * m[1] * m[10] + m[4] * m[2] * m[9]  + m[8]  * m[1] * m[6]  - m[8]  * m[2] * m[5];

    det = m[0] * inv[0] + m[1] * inv[4] + m[2] * inv[8] + m[3] * inv[12];
    if (det == 0) return false;
    det = 1.0 / det;

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        invOut[i] = inv[i] * det;

    return true;
}
```