# Performing high number of 4x4 matrix inversion - PyCuda

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am looking for a solution with Python to perform matrix inversions. I think there should be a way with CUBLAS or MAGMA to execute these operations in a batch or concurrent mode since each matrix is independent of all the others.

So I am looking for feedback for this specific problem and see if CUBLAS or MAGMA have solutions to carry out this batch or parallel execution.

I think that the calculations proposed here should be ideal for a GPU.

I have got to find a 2D range kernel with range `(integ_prec,integ_prec)` where the kernel performs a 4x4 matrix inversion of the given global item.

How can I implement this kernel code? I have tested the `batch_solver` provided by NVIDIA developpers but I can't get to make it work.

### Update 1

To answer to @Robert Crovella, I tried to use the BatchSolver
from NVIDIA developpers ( version `BatchedSolver_v1_1`).

You can see below the warnings I get during compilation :

```
$ make
nvcc -O3  -arch=sm_35 -DKEPLER2  -o example_batch_solver example.c solve.cu inverse.cu
In file included from solve.cu:41:
./operations.h:31:2: warning: 'OPERATIONS_H_' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#if !defined(OPERATIONS_H_)
 ^~
./operations.h:32:9: note: 'OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_' is defined here; did you mean 'OPERATIONS_H_'?
#define OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        OPERATIONS_H_
1 warning generated.
In file included from solve.cu:41:
./operations.h:31:2: warning: 'OPERATIONS_H_' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#if !defined(OPERATIONS_H_)
 ^~
./operations.h:32:9: note: 'OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_' is defined here; did you mean 'OPERATIONS_H_'?
#define OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        OPERATIONS_H_
1 warning generated.
In file included from inverse.cu:44:
./operations.h:31:2: warning: 'OPERATIONS_H_' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#if !defined(OPERATIONS_H_)
 ^~
./operations.h:32:9: note: 'OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_' is defined here; did you mean 'OPERATIONS_H_'?
#define OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        OPERATIONS_H_
1 warning generated.

In file included from inverse.cu:44:
./operations.h:31:2: warning: 'OPERATIONS_H_' is used as a header guard here, followed by #define of a different macro [-Wheader-guard]
#if !defined(OPERATIONS_H_)
 ^~
./operations.h:32:9: note: 'OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_' is defined here; did you mean 'OPERATIONS_H_'?
#define OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H_
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        OPERATIONS_H_
1 warning generated.
```

Unfortunately, the execution gives bad results :

```
Non-batched matrix inversion

        3.000000   1.000000   1.000000             nan  -19945373249087470322107824313046586886748897396355850773313316907920980812816123986073723926411981165664742747916855157931798956499818437291518879567207778108249202114071816066955302634366146096749274721347289725502062211559628338200162202651585616465674552041292175081655027073691104118308864.000000  -25949369271932562088528097628985580835309378491979298170251656488819244813241392783541154149164125403081303093429316785499097407170772831834462454013755392.000000
etc ...
```

So, to avoid these warnings, I replaced the macro `OPERATIONS_SOLVE_H` by `OPERATIONS_H_`into `operations.h` file. No more warnings during compilation but still bad results at execution (same than above).

Anyone has got the same issues about this `Batchsolver` (on `MacOS 10.13.5` with `NVIDIA driver 387.10.10.10.35.106` and CUDA-10.0)?

Comment: no, you can't use numpy functions directly in pycuda kernel code.

Comment: @talonmies . Could you take please a look at my **UPDATE 2**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1148309/681865

Comment: cublas has a batched `matinv` function that can handle batch inversion of small matrices (up to side dimension 32).  However this function isn't already available in either the [pyculib cublas interface](https://pyculib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cublas.html) or the [scikit-cuda cublas interface](https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_cublas.html) (scikit-cuda does provide batched `getrf` functions but not batched `getri`, so that path is also incomplete).  It should be possible with some work to interface via python ctypes i.e. generic python-to-C interfacing.

Comment: NVIDIA used to provide a free download called `BatchedSolver_v1_1.tgz` which had the ability to solve batches of small systems or do batched matrix inversion.  I'm not sure if that is what you were referring to with "`batch_solver` provided by NVIDIA ".  That method should be workable directly in pycuda.  However stating " I can't get to make it work" doesn't provide any useful information to make forward progress there.  The link provided by talonmies might be a very simple direct method of doing this - write your own pycuda kernel with that code.

Comment: @RobertCrovella . I give you more results about my issues with `BatchedSolver_v1_1.tgz` . feel free to tell me any suggestions, regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, numpy functions in general cannot be used from pycuda kernel code (or CUDA kernel code, or numba cuda kernels).

CUBLAS offers a [batched matrix inversion function](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-matinvbatched), but it is not currently exposed in either [pyculib cublas interface](https://pyculib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cublas.html) or [scikit-cuda cublas interface](https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_cublas.html).

We could proceed to implement our own interface (e.g. using python `ctypes`), but since its known that the matrices to be inverted are 4x4, I thought the suggestion in the comments from talonmies was an interesting one.  Referring to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1148405/1695960), there is a fairly concise C code to do a direct inversion of a 4x4 matrix.

What follows first is a realization of this in CUDA.  The function `inv4x4` is an adaptation of the previous code, allotting 16 threads per matrix (one per matrix element) and using that code as a model.  Each thread is responsible for computing one result matrix element.  First we will compare it to CUBLAS `matinvBatched` for performance:

```
$ cat t411.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <cstdlib>
// 4x4 matrix inversion
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148309/inverting-a-4x4-matrix

// assumes warp size is 32
// assumes block size is multiple of warp size
// therefore assumes number of matrices to be inverted (n) is even
// 16 threads per matrix to invert

const unsigned block_size = 256;
typedef float mt;

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

__device__ unsigned pat[3][16];
const unsigned hpat[3][16] = {
{ 0x0EB51FA5, 0x1EB10FA1, 0x0E711F61, 0x1A710B61, 0x1EB40FA4, 0x0EB01FA0, 0x1E700F60, 0x0A701B60, 0x0DB41F94, 0x1DB00F90, 0x0D701F50, 0x19700B50, 0x1DA40E94, 0x0DA01E90, 0x1D600E50, 0x09601A50},
{ 0x1E790F69, 0x0E391F29, 0x1E350F25, 0x0A351B25, 0x0E781F68, 0x1E380F28, 0x0E341F24, 0x1A340B24, 0x1D780F58, 0x0D381F18, 0x1D340F14, 0x09341B14, 0x0D681E58, 0x1D280E18, 0x0D241E14, 0x19240A14},
{ 0x0A7D1B6D, 0x1A3D0B2D, 0x063D172D, 0x16390729, 0x1A7C0B6C, 0x0A3C1B2C, 0x163C072C, 0x06381728, 0x097C1B5C, 0x193C0B1C, 0x053C171C, 0x15380718, 0x196C0A5C, 0x092C1A1C, 0x152C061C, 0x05281618}};

__device__ unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
  unsigned ret = off & 0x0F;
  off = off >> 4;
  return ret;
}

const unsigned tmsk = 0xFFFFFFFF;
// in-place is acceptable i.e. out == in)
// T = float or double only
template <typename T>
__global__ void inv4x4(const T * __restrict__ in, T * __restrict__ out, const size_t n){

  __shared__ T si[block_size];
  size_t idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < n*16){
    si[threadIdx.x] = in[idx];
    unsigned lane = threadIdx.x & 15;
    unsigned sibase = threadIdx.x & 0x03F0;
    __syncwarp();
    unsigned off = pat[0][lane];
    T a,b;
    a  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    a *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    a *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (!getoff(off)) a = -a;
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    off = pat[1][lane];
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    off = pat[2][lane];
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    T det = si[sibase + (lane>>2)]*a;
    det += __shfl_down_sync(tmsk, det, 4, 16); // first add
    det += __shfl_down_sync(tmsk, det, 8, 16); // second add
    det =  __shfl_sync(tmsk, det, 0, 16); // broadcast
    out[idx] = a / det;
  }
}

size_t nr = 2048;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if (argc > 1) nr = atoi(argv[1]);

  const mt m1[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0};
  const mt i1[] = {-3.0, -0.5, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.25, -0.25, -0.5, 3.0, 0.25, -1.25, -0.5, -3.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
  const mt m2[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};
  const mt i2[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};

  mt *h_d, *d_d;
  h_d = (mt *)malloc(nr*2*16*sizeof(mt));
  cudaMalloc(&d_d, nr*2*16*sizeof(mt));
  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(pat, hpat, 3*16*sizeof(unsigned));
  for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++){
    memcpy(h_d+i*16*2, m1, sizeof(m1));
    memcpy(h_d+i*16*2+16, m2, sizeof(m2));}
  cudaMemcpy(d_d, h_d, nr*2*16*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  long long t = dtime_usec(0);
  inv4x4<<<nr*2*16/block_size, block_size>>>(d_d, d_d, nr*2);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  t = dtime_usec(t);
  cudaMemcpy(h_d, d_d, nr*2*16*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) std::cout << h_d[i*16 + j] << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) std::cout << ((i==0)?i1[j]:i2[j]) << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;}
  std::cout << "kernel time: " << t << " microseconds" << std::endl;
  cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
  //cublas
  for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++){
    memcpy(h_d+i*16*2, m1, sizeof(m1));
    memcpy(h_d+i*16*2+16, m2, sizeof(m2));}
  cudaMemcpy(d_d, h_d, nr*2*16*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cublasHandle_t h;
  cublasStatus_t cs = cublasCreate(&h);
  if (cs != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) std::cout << "cublas create error" << std::endl;
  mt **A, **Ai, *Aid, **Ap, **Aip;
  A  = (mt **)malloc(nr*2*sizeof(mt *));
  Ai = (mt **)malloc(nr*2*sizeof(mt *));
  cudaMalloc(&Aid, nr*2*16*sizeof(mt));
  cudaMalloc(&Ap,  nr*2*sizeof(mt *));
  cudaMalloc(&Aip, nr*2*sizeof(mt *));
  for (int i = 0; i < nr*2; i++) A[i]  =  d_d + 16*i;
  for (int i = 0; i < nr*2; i++) Ai[i] =  Aid + 16*i;
  cudaMemcpy(Ap, A, nr*2*sizeof(mt *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cudaMemcpy(Aip, Ai, nr*2*sizeof(mt *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  int *info;
  cudaMalloc(&info, nr*2*sizeof(int));
  t = dtime_usec(0);
  cs = cublasSmatinvBatched(h, 4,  Ap, 4, Aip, 4, info, nr*2);
  if (cs != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) std::cout << "cublas matinv error" << std::endl;
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  t = dtime_usec(t);
  cudaMemcpy(h_d, Aid, nr*2*16*sizeof(mt), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) std::cout << h_d[i*16 + j] << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) std::cout << ((i==0)?i1[j]:i2[j]) << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;}
  std::cout << "cublas time: " << t << " microseconds" << std::endl;
  err = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err != cudaSuccess) std::cout << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t411 t411.cu -lcublas
$ ./t411
-3,-0.5,1.5,1,1,0.25,-0.25,-0.5,3,0.25,-1.25,-0.5,-3,-0,1,1,
-3,-0.5,1.5,1,1,0.25,-0.25,-0.5,3,0.25,-1.25,-0.5,-3,0,1,1,
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,
kernel time: 49 microseconds
-3,-0.5,1.5,1,1,0.25,-0.25,-0.5,3,0.25,-1.25,-0.5,-3,0,1,1,
-3,-0.5,1.5,1,1,0.25,-0.25,-0.5,3,0.25,-1.25,-0.5,-3,0,1,1,
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,
cublas time: 95 microseconds
$
```

We see that the code appears to provide the correct result for 2 test matrices inverted, and the overall time to invert 4096 matrices on a Tesla P100 is about 50us and is about 2x faster than CUBLAS.  **Note that I have not exhaustively tested this code.**

What follows next is a simple pycuda implementation of a similar function.  Here, for simplicity we are just inverting 2 matrices:

```
$ cat t10.py
import numpy as np
import pycuda.driver as cuda
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.autoinit
# kernel
kernel = SourceModule("""

__device__ unsigned getoff(unsigned &off){
  unsigned ret = off & 0x0F;
  off = off >> 4;
  return ret;
}

const int block_size = 256;
const unsigned tmsk = 0xFFFFFFFF;
// in-place is acceptable i.e. out == in)
// T = float or double only
typedef float T;
__global__ void inv4x4(const T * __restrict__ in, T * __restrict__ out, const size_t n, const unsigned * __restrict__ pat){

  __shared__ T si[block_size];
  size_t idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  if (idx < n*16){
    si[threadIdx.x] = in[idx];
    unsigned lane = threadIdx.x & 15;
    unsigned sibase = threadIdx.x & 0x03F0;
    __syncwarp();
    unsigned off = pat[lane];
    T a,b;
    a  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    a *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    a *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (!getoff(off)) a = -a;
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    off = pat[lane+16];
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    off = pat[lane+32];
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    b  = si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    b *= si[sibase + getoff(off)];
    if (getoff(off)) a += b;
    else a -=b;
    T det = si[sibase + (lane>>2)]*a;
    det += __shfl_down_sync(tmsk, det, 4, 16); // first add
    det += __shfl_down_sync(tmsk, det, 8, 16); // second add
    det =  __shfl_sync(tmsk, det, 0, 16); // broadcast
    out[idx] = a / det;
  }
}

""")
# python function for inverting 4x4 matrices
# n should be an even number
def gpuinv4x4(inp, n):
    # internal constants not to be modified
    hpat = ( 0x0EB51FA5, 0x1EB10FA1, 0x0E711F61, 0x1A710B61, 0x1EB40FA4, 0x0EB01FA0, 0x1E700F60, 0x0A701B60, 0x0DB41F94, 0x1DB00F90, 0x0D701F50, 0x19700B50, 0x1DA40E94, 0x0DA01E90, 0x1D600E50, 0x09601A50, 0x1E790F69, 0x0E391F29, 0x1E350F25, 0x0A351B25, 0x0E781F68, 0x1E380F28, 0x0E341F24, 0x1A340B24, 0x1D780F58, 0x0D381F18, 0x1D340F14, 0x09341B14, 0x0D681E58, 0x1D280E18, 0x0D241E14, 0x19240A14, 0x0A7D1B6D, 0x1A3D0B2D, 0x063D172D, 0x16390729, 0x1A7C0B6C, 0x0A3C1B2C, 0x163C072C, 0x06381728, 0x097C1B5C, 0x193C0B1C, 0x053C171C, 0x15380718, 0x196C0A5C, 0x092C1A1C, 0x152C061C, 0x05281618)
    # Convert parameters into numpy array
    inpd = np.array(inp, dtype=np.float32)
    hpatd = np.array(hpat, dtype=np.uint32)
    output = np.empty((n*16), dtype= np.float32)
    # Get kernel function
    matinv4x4 = kernel.get_function("inv4x4")
    # Define block, grid and compute
    blockDim = (256,1,1) # do not change
    gridDim = ((n/16)+1,1,1)
    # Kernel function
    matinv4x4 (
        cuda.In(inpd), cuda.Out(output), np.uint64(n), cuda.In(hpatd),
        block=blockDim, grid=gridDim)
    return output
#example/test case
inp = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
n = 2
result = gpuinv4x4(inp, n)
print(result)
$ python t10.py
[-3.   -0.5   1.5   1.    1.    0.25 -0.25 -0.5   3.    0.25 -1.25 -0.5  -3.
 -0.    1.    1.    1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.    0.    0.    0.    0.
  1.    0.    0.    0.    0.    1.  ]
$
```

I've spent very little time creating this pycuda test case, so please consider it as a rough demonstration vehicle.

I suspect that if the only thing you need to do in CUDA is invert these matrices, this won't be an interesting or attractive use case.  I expect that the cost to transfer the data to the device and return the results back would outweigh any speed-up benefit from using the GPU, vs. ordinary numpy.  However I haven't tested or benchmarked a numpy case.

Note that the use of `__syncwarp()` means this kernel code requires CUDA 9.0 or later.

Also note that the code expects an even number of matrices to invert.  If you don't have an even number, pad your array with any value to the next even number of matrices.

Also note that the code just assumes the matrices are invertible.  There is no test to see if they are not, and for example if the determinant computed were zero, the matrix would not be invertible (using this method) and the results would typically be NaN, due to division-by-zero.

It's not clear what the purpose is here, so this example should not be construed to suggest that general matrix inversion is a good idea or a proper solution method for a particular problem.

Probably a better pythonic method for inversion of dense matrices on the GPU would be to use [cupy](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.linalg.inv.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer. Just a precision, what does `hpat = ( 0x0EB51FA5, 0x1EB10FA1, ...` array correspond to ? I don't understand why one uses hexa values. Regards

Comment: That array is used in the device code to generate the index patterns needed by each thread as it is loading and multiplying the data from the input.  Each value corresponds to a particular multiply sequence.  Hexadecimal makes it easier because each index generated corresponds to 4 bits, which is one hexadecimal digit.

Comment: But how to calculate these hexadecimal values ? Are they always the same or it depends on others paramters like the size of batch or size of arrays used ?

Comment: They are always the same for 4x4 matrix inversion.  They are not to be changed by the user ever.  I've modified the posted code a bit to make it a bit clearer that these are internal constants used by the function, not supplied by the user of the function.  The python function to use is just `gpuinv4x4()` which just takes an array of the matrices to be inverted and the number of matrices in the array (that should be an even number).

Comment: That is really a different question.  This code is specific to 4x4 matricies, there is not a general or straightforward adaptation to 3x3.  It would be a complete rewrite.  You can ask a new question if you wish.

Comment: A similar code (3x3) is now extensively described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056195/understanding-in-details-the-algorithm-for-inversion-of-a-high-number-of-3x3-mat).  There are only a few conceptual changes going from 3x3 to 4x4 code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailled answer !